# Can a GObject signal return a non-gobject object?

Tags: pygtk, pygobject, gobject

The callback function has to return a custom non-GObject class's object, Can a GObject have such a callback?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be included as one of the later arguments. The first argument in the signal callback is always the object which is emitting the signal (which has to be a GObject, otherwise it can’t be emitting a GObject signal).

Without a concrete example of your code, or what’s not working for you, it’s hard to answer in any more detail.